# what does OpenID 'Sign in with OpenID using simple registration' mean?

Tags: django, openid

I used openid, and when after successfully authenticating, it returned:

```
You are signed in as http://zjm1126.myopenid.com/
Sign in with OpenID | Sign in with OpenID using simple registration | Sign in with OpenID, testing ?next= param | Sign out
```

I want to know the meaning of:

1. Sign in with OpenID using simple registration
2. Sign in with OpenID, testing ?next= param

thanks

Comment: That's some seriously bad UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On what website is that?

"Simple registration" probably refers to the [sreg extension](http://openid.net/specs/openid-simple-registration-extension-1_0.html):

> OpenID Simple Registation is an extension to the OpenID Authentication protocol that allows for very light-weight profile exchange. It is designed to pass eight commonly requested pieces of information when an End User goes to register a new account with a web service.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine if you log in with sreg it will request some of the sreg params (email, firstname, lastname) and you will be able to grant access to them.  Not all sites support sreg so will not send back the data unless they do.